# Unix commands not working in remote server when executed from local server?

Tags: shell, unix

I have file test2.txt which contains name of the files present in remote server. However I have placed this script in my local server along with this file test2.txt.
I want to execute this script on local server to find out the files which are mentioned in text2.txt are present in remote server or not. If they exists I want to move 
them in a specific directory in the remote server itself. However this code not working in remote server after establishing the connection with remote server i.e. after 
for i in $(ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" username@hostname cat apps/dir/test2.txt);

Below is the snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" username@hostname cat apps/dir/test2.txt);
do
if [ ! -d $BACKUP ]; then
    mkdir BACKUP
fi
file_exists=find /apps/dir/ -type f -name "$i"  -print
cp apps/dir/$file_exists BACKUP
echo "The path is: $file_exists"
done
```

Comment: How is it not working? Error messages, unexpected behavior, or something else?

Comment: No error message. For example the mkdir command is creating the BACKUP directory in local server instead of creating it in remote server. Similar behavior is observed for subsequent command.

Comment: Why do you think the mkdir or anything after it would be executed remotely? It's not inside the ssh.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Yes I can observe that. Can you please help me out to whole thing work(which is mentioned in the snippet)?